# In VisualSVN is it possible to ignore project folders that don't belong to a solution in update operation

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

We have a directory structure that includes all our company's projects under a single root directory. Our Visual Studio solutions are located in the root directory so that common projects can be shared between solutions without having to manage multiple copies for them. Unfortunately, when any user tries to perform an update operation on the solution they are working on, they get an update of all the project files that are located in the folders below the solution file directory which means they get all the changed files in all the projects even if they are not relevant at all. This obviously takes a lot of time and clutters users' local drives with unnecessary files.
Does anyone know if there is a method in VisualSVN/TortoiseSVN to ignore any file/folder/project that is not part of a specific Visual Studio solution?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It really sounds like you need to make each directory a separate VisualSVN project